# Very new to XSLT! Having difficulty adding new line between records

Tags: xslt

I have a soap xml output and need to convert it to plain text file. I am trying to use xsltproc. Got the following xsl tempalate online

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'|'" />

    <csv:columns><column>Numbers</column></csv:columns>

    <xsl:template match="getNumbersResponse">
        <xsl:variable name="property" select="." />

        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My soap xml output is as follows

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>
<ns4:getNumbersResponse xmlns:ns4="http://service.engine.com"><ns4:Numbers>100</ns4:Numbers>
<ns4:Numbers>200</ns4:Numbers>
</ns4:getNumbersResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I try xsltproc using the above xsl tempalate to transform this xml output, I get records in following format

100200

I want to add a new line between each record. Found online that adding following line should do it but I do not see any changes in the output with or without this line in xsl template.

```
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
```

I would want my output to be like this

```
Numbers|
100|
200|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet doesn't actually do anything, because your only template does not match anything in the source XML. The output you see is purely the result of the built-in template rules.

If you want to get a return-separated list of the `ns4:Numbers` values, you should do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns4="http://service.engine.com">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope">
    <xsl:for-each select="soapenv:Body/ns4:getNumbersResponse/ns4:Numbers">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
             <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of declared prefixes to address the nodes in your XML.

---

To get the result in your edited question, do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns4="http://service.engine.com">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope">
    <xsl:text>Numbers|&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="soapenv:Body/ns4:getNumbersResponse/ns4:Numbers">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>|&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked great! Appreciate all your help!

Comment: Sure would do that! One more help please - Is there any way I can get header also added in the beginning of transformed output. Thanks very much!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Please edit your question and show the exact output you expect to get.

Comment: I did edit my question with expected output. Thanks!

Comment: @Amaya See the addition to my answer.